# Spring MongoDB data can not fetch @DBRef objects with "find" query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

There is an object a classic POJO as below:

```java
@Document
public class MyPojo {
  @DBRef
  @Field("otherPojo")
  private List<OtherPojo> otherPojos;
}
```

And `OtherPojo.java`:

```
public class OtherPojo{
  @Id
  private ObjectId _id;
  private String someOtherFields;
}
```

I can not cascade-save these, but I'm getting over it by saving DBRefs first and then saving my POJO list, but still when I try to fetch all list or querying some of them with below code:

```
Query query = new Query( Criteria.where( "myPojo.blabla" ).is( "blabla" ) );
List<MyPojo> resultList = mongoTemplate.find( query, MyPojo.class, "myCollection" );
```

it returns me with a list of null DBrefs, it counts true. For example: there are saved 10 DBRefs it returns 10 null object in it, but its primitive types and other types that aren't a DBRref are all non-null.
How can i handle this ?

I save my objects as below:

```
for (MyPojo pojo : somePojoList) {
    for (OtherPojo otherPojo : pojo.getOtherPojos()) {
        mongoTemplate.save(otherPojo, "myCollection");
    }
}

// ...

mongoTemplate.insert( myPojoList, "myCollection" );
```

**EDIT:** OK, now I know if I do not specify a collection name when I'm saving otherPojos, I can fetch them (thanks to @jmen7070). But I have to write myCollection there because I'm dropping and re-creating them always. That's a use-case. So how can I say "find method to use same collection to fetch DBRefs"?

Comment: Can you give more detail about how do you save objects in data base?

Comment: I’m also facing same issue, please let me what is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references):

> The mapping framework does not handle cascading saves. If you change
>   an Account object that is referenced by a Person object, you must save
>   the Account object separately. Calling save on the Person object will
>   not automatically save the Account objects in the property accounts.

So, first, you have to save each object of the otherPojos list. After that you can save MyPojo instance:

```
MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
OtherPojo otherPojo = new OtherPojo();
OtherPojo otherPojo1 = new OtherPojo();

pojo.setOtherPojos(Arrays.asList(otherPojo, otherPojo1));

mongoTemplate.save(otherPojo);
mongoTemplate.save(otherPojo1);

mongoTemplate.save(pojo);
```

**UPDATED:**
You saved a objects:

```
for( MyPojo pojo : somePojoList ){
            for( OtherPojo otherPojo : pojo.getOtherPojos() ){
                mongoTemplate.save( otherPojo,collectionname );
            }
        }
```

All otherPojo objects will be saved in collection with name "collectionName"..

but your myPojo objects have a $ref to an otherPojo collection..

```
"otherPojo" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "otherPojo",
            "$id" : ObjectId("535f9100ad52e59815755cef")
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "otherPojo",
            "$id" : ObjectId("535f9101ad52e59815755cf0")
        }
    ]
```

So, "collectionname" variable

```
 mongoTemplate.save( otherPojo,collectionname );
```

must be "otherPojo".

To avoid confusion, I propose to specify a collection for saving OtherPojo objects with @Doucument annotation:

```
@Document(collection="otherPojos")
public class OtherPojo{

@Id
private ObjectId _id;
private String someOtherFields;

}
```

And to save otherPojo objects by using a overloaded save() method of mongoTemplate

```
mongoTemplate.save( otherPojo );
```

In this way , you will have a valid $ref for myPojo documents

UPDATE 2:

In this case, you want to store parents and childs object in same collection.

To achieve this you can use [this approach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: no !! you misunderstood, read again that part:

`ok, now i can not cascade save these but i get over it by saving DBRefs first and then saving my pojo list, but still when i try to fetch all list or querying some of them with below code:`

Comment: ok, i followed your suggestions, i succesfuly fetch them now, but i have to specify a collection name to it.. I can give it a different collection name does it solve ?

Comment: I don't understand your last question, sorry) What is your goal? Which collections do  you want to save objects?

Comment: Ok i have a couple of collections, and iam always dropping re-creating them. This is a use-case, and i cant change that.

So, now i have to specify same collection name for "MyPojo" and "OtherPojo" and also when i use find method, im passing this collection name in it. 

I'm editing question please see there.

Comment: If you will store "MyPojo" and "OtherPojo" objects in same collection, maybe, you should not to use DBRef.. You can store Other Pojos embedded in MyPojo documents.

Comment: But it is too big too keep it like that i mean otherPojo > 16 MB

Comment: Do you have Skype? i can try to help)